# Install Geospatial Modelling Environment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, installation, gme

I install Geospatial Modelling ([GME](http://www.spatialecology.com/gme/gmedownload.htm)) Environment in ArcGIS 10.2. But I can't find where is. I search to ArcGIS and ArcToolbox and as a standalone App but I can't find it.

Comment: The very link you gave states on the very top line of the first paragraph: _GME is a stand-alone program that can be started from the Windows Start button -- Programs -- SpatialEcology. It has both a GUI interface (mouse-driven) and a command line interface for scripting._

Answer (score 2):

I believe that it is under Spatial Ecology, in the Start Menu.

Answer (score 1):

First of all thank you all for your comments and answers. I had to use it some years and the last time it was an add-on in ArcGIS. The second problem it was that I use 3.1.2 R and the recommendation is 3.1.1 . I remove the new version and I keep the older 3.1.1 and it was finally find it and work perfect.